# Getting error no declared type in bison

Tags: c, header, bison, flex-lexer

I am doing my homework assignment and I am having some errors in the bison file. I got error like 'blabla' has no declared type. My code and errors are below. I am trying do a type checker, I have a header, flex and a bison file. Flex returning the tokens that I need. I wrote a function to make an attribute, then I check if the two attribute types are the same or not. If not same, I will give an error output, but when I compile it I got these errors. I did not figure it out. What did I do  wrong?

In bison file:

```
   AttrNode * makeATTR(char * v, AttrType t);

%union
{
    ValType val; 
    char *text;
    AttrNode *attrPtr;
}
%token <text> tOPEN tCLOSE tSELF tLEND tCOURSE tCLASS ....continue
        day_type:       tMON { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        | tTUE  { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        | tWED  { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        | tTHU  { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        | tFRI  { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        ;
        attr_val:       tSTRING {$$= makeATTR($1,STRING);}
                        | tNUM  {$$= makeATTR($2,NUMBER);}
                        | tTIME {$$ = makeATTR($3,TIME);}
                        | day_type { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        ;
        attr_name:      tNAME {$$= makeATTR($1,STRING);}
                        | tCODE {$$= makeATTR($1,STRING);}
                        | tTYPE {$$= makeATTR($1,STRING);}
                        | tCRN {$$= makeATTR($2,NUMBER);}
                        | tSECTION {$$= makeATTR($1,STRING);}
                        | tCAPACITY {$$= makeATTR($2,NUMBER);}
                        | tSTART {$$ = makeATTR($3,TIME);}
                        | tEND {$$ = makeATTR($3,TIME);}
                        | tDAY { $$ = makeATTR ($1,DAY);}
                        ;
        attribute:      attr_name attr_val  {if($1.type!=$2.type)
                                                printf("Mismatch error");}
    ....

 AttrNode * makeATTR(char * v, AttrType t)
 {
     AttrNode * ret = (AttrNode*) malloc(sizeof(AttrNode));
     result->thisNodeType = Attr;
     result->attrNodePtr = (AttrNode*)malloc(sizeof(AttrNode));
     result->attrNodePtr->AttrNode.value=v;
     result->attrNodePtr->AttrNode.type=t;
    return (result);
 }
```

In .h file

```
typedef enum {Attr,Tree } NodeType;
typedef enum {STRING,NUMBER,TIME,DAY} AttrType;
//For String
typedef struct AttrNode
{
    char * value; 
    AttrType * type;
}AttrNode;

 typedef struct TreeNode
 {
 NodeType thisNodeType; 
 AttrNode *attrNodePtr; 
 }TreeNode;

AttrNode * makeATTR(char * v, AttrType t);
```

Errors

> hw4.y:25.24-25: $$ of `day_type' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:26.27-28: $$ of `day_type' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:27.27-28: $$ of `day_type' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:28.27-28: $$ of `day_type' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:29.27-28: $$ of `day_type' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:31.26-27: $$ of `attr_val' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:32.26-27: $$ of `attr_val' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:32.39-40: integer out of range: `$2'
>   hw4.y:33.26-27: $$ of `attr_val' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:33.40-41: integer out of range: `$3'
>   hw4.y:34.30-31: $$ of `attr_val' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:34.45-46: $1 of `attr_val' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:36.24-25: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:37.26-27: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:38.32-33: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:39.26-27: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:40.25-26: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:40.38-39: integer out of range: `$2'
>   hw4.y:41.29-30: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:42.30-31: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:42.43-44: integer out of range: `$2'
>   hw4.y:43.27-28: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:43.41-42: integer out of range: `$3'
>   hw4.y:44.25-26: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:44.39-40: integer out of range: `$3'
>   hw4.y:45.26-27: $$ of `attr_name' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:47.41-42: $1 of `attribute' has no declared type
>   hw4.y:47.50-51: $2 of `attribute' has no declared type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tell bison/yacc that there is more than one semantic type (with a `%union` declaration), then you can only use `$n` and `$$` for terminals and non-terminals with declared types. In this case, bison is telling you that you are attempting to set `$$` for a non-terminal with no declared type. That's not possible because bison cannot generate an appropriate assignment statement without knowing which union member to assign to.

So you need to declare the types of your non-terminals:

```
%type <something> day_type attr_val ...
```

Also, you have `$n` references which are out of bounds. For example, in the production:

```
attr_val: ...
        | tNUM  {$$= makeATTR($2,NUMBER);}
```

the right-hand side consists of exactly one symbol (`tNUM`), so there is no `$2`. Hence the error message ("integer out of range: `$2'"). I presume you meant `$1`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that the %type is necessary. Now it's working!